# How to check if Xml-Root element tag closed?

Tags: c#, xml

I am recieving XML-Datas from server which is like:

```
<SystemAsync timestamp="1289734897" status="stopped" time="0"/>
```

or :

```
<SystemAsync timestamp="1289734897" status="stopped" time="0">
    <AntTable antstatus="ready" active="1"/>
</SystemAsync>
```

There is no problem parsing the xml. But server can send the xml-data in 2 splitted parts

1.part of xml-data

```
<SystemAsync timestamp="1289734897" status="stopped" time="0">
    <AntTable antstatus="ready" active="1"/>
```

2.part of xml data:

```
</SystemAsync>
```

How can I check, if the xml data is not ended, so I can wait for 2. part.?

This is an Server/Client Socket System.

My server recieves XML-Datas from the rootserver, and sends the xml-data to all clients.

Thank you!

Comment: you *could* check whether the current data is invalid xml, if so wait for more data ;-)

Comment: Maybe you can simply test if the received file is a valid xml.

Comment: Can the server not simply tell you the total length (bytes) or numer of fragments?

Comment: @MarcGravell, No, server does not send the length, I only get the length of the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server needs to delimit the message it's sending. It basically needs to tell you when it's done.

Basing your code on "when do I stop getting an exception" is not a good idea. What if you *never* stop getting an exception?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this particular case question could be more generalized to a problem of entire XML document validation. Considering that sending a data in multiple chunks is a valid case - it would be great if communion protocol you're using would provide you somethik like EndOfStream marker/message to indicate that all data is sent. Many messaging systems provides built in support of feature like Message Index/Sequence Number, perhaps protocol you're suing support it so you can enable it whilst initializing a connection, take a look documentation if such is provided.

Otherwise you've to perform check each time you've received next one chunk.

Useful links:

- [Message Sequence](http://eaipatterns.com/MessageSequence.html) enterprise design pattern

Comment: Server is always sending valid xml, I will try to check for validation

Comment: Are you using self made communication or some messaging system?

Comment: its not selfmade communication. I have made server/client, but my server is recieving from another server(provider)

Comment: Ok if communication between server and client is not self made which one of standard messaging systems/protocols are you using?